# Find all the macro declarations as string using clang preprocessor?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define engine_exhaust_gas_temperature_raw 100
#define engine_exhaust_gas_temperature_scaled 20

#define Sum(x, y) ( ( x )+ ( y ) )


int main(){
    
    printf("%d",engine_exhaust_gas_temperature_raw);

    return 0;
}
```

I am working on MISRA C **Rule 5.4 Macro identifiers shall be distinct** for which I need the list of the names of all the macros defined in a C program as strings.

> For ex: In the above code I will need:
>
> [ "engine_exhaust_gas_temperature_raw", "engine_exhaust_gas_temperature_scaled", "Sum"]

Is there any way to get this list using clang AST?

I have found that we can use clangs https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html Preprocessor class to get the iterator to macros but even this is not producing any output for me. I have used it in the below code. What am I missing here?

```
bool distinct_macro_identifier(CompilerInstance *C_I, ASTContext *Context){
  
  auto st= C_I->getPreprocessor().macro_begin()->getFirst()->getName();

  auto x= C_I->getPreprocessor().macro_begin()->first;

  llvm::outs()<<x->getName()<<"\n";

  auto p= C_I->getPreprocessor().getMacroInfo(x);

  p->dump();

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile it with this command:

```
clang++ -E -dM  -nostdlib file.cpp
```